# where to place notifyDataSetChanged(); in customAdapter so listView doesn't lose data on scroll

Tags: android, listview

I know there is information online about notifyDataSetChanged(); and how to use it but I can't seem to be able to figure out how to use it for my exact situation. I don't know if I should call it in my activity, adapter class or what. I just want the listView to not change the text the user previously inputted to go back to the default text when the row scrolls off the screen.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ArrayList<String> Chores = new ArrayList<>();
        Chores.add("");

        final ListAdapter MyAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, Chores);
        ListView listViewObject = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.customListView_ID);
        listViewObject.setAdapter(MyAdapter);

        listViewObject.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                    String ChoreString = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));




                }
            }

        );
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ID);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Chores.add("");
                ((ArrayAdapter)MyAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        });




    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.example.emilythacker.chorelist.R.id.textView_ID;



class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList choreText) {
        super(context, R.layout.custon_listview_row, choreText);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.custon_listview_row, parent, false);


        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_ID);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(textView_ID);





        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //what happens when textView is clicked
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
                final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());
                input.setHint("hint");
                alertDialog.setView(input);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Set Chore");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                //this will set text to "hello" only if user does not enter anything into input
                                //textView.setText("hello");

                                //this also will only work if there is no input entered into input...wich will change textView into empty space
                                textView.setText(input.getText().toString());




                                //works the same with or without dialog.dismiss();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });



        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.clock);


        return customView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not caused by notifyDataSetChanged(); but because you are not reusing your view in your adapter and not setting the data you want to set in your getView()

Better try to use viewholder pattern or use recyclerview.

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    ArrayList<String> choreText;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList choreText) {
        super(context, R.layout.custon_listview_row, choreText);
        this.choreText = choreText;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custon_listview_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageButton = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_ID);
            holder.textView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(textView_ID);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView.setText(choreText.get(position));
        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //what happens when textView is clicked
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
                final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());
                input.setHint("hint");
                alertDialog.setView(input);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Set Chore");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                //this will set text to "hello" only if user does not enter anything into input
                                //textView.setText("hello");

                                //this also will only work if there is no input entered into input...wich will change textView into empty space
                                textView.setText(input.getText().toString());




                                //works the same with or without dialog.dismiss();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });



        holder.imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.clock);


        return customView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageButton imageButton;
        TextView textView;
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is list_entry?

Comment: Sorry, it should be your row layout ID, I just edited the answer, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't add empty strings into the list.Remove all `Chores.add("");` from your MainActivity.

2.On scroll it will recreate the views better option to use the view holder though.

3.To preserve the view data, create one array which will store the text data of your edittext.

```
// initialise the array inside constructor
     stringArray = new String[choreText.size()] ;
```

4.On every ok click save the data into the array and call notifyDataSetChanged

```
  alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NE UTRAL, "OK",    new    DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
   { public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

  //this will set text to "hello" only if user does   not enter anything into input 
   textView.setText("hello");

    //this also will only work if there is no input entered into input...which will change textView into empty space

   textView.setText(input.getText().toString());  
   stringArray[position]=input.getText().toString();
   notifyDataSetChanged();

     //works the same with or without
   dialog.dismiss(); dialog.dismiss(); } });
```

4.Set the preserved text from array ,Inside your getview add this line

```
textview.setText(stringArray[position]==null?"":stringArray[position];
```